# What metrics can be used to determine good technique/posture?

Tags: guitar, piano, technique, posture, violin-family

I am feeling a bit inspired by using physical laws to guide technique, like how Newton's laws are used here to give guidelines for bow hold: https://www.violinist.com/blog/fjt/20215/28767/. My idea is to model a human by for example a skeleton as rigid bodies and tendons and and ligaments as strings and then measuring how 'good' different limb positions are from things like pressure or tension in them (possibly muscles too but they are so complex so I don't know how to model them). I don't really know what identifies good technique besides not using more force than necessary, and using force smart so you don't accidentally cancel yourself out so to speak. Does anyone know what kind of metrics could be good to evaluate "good technique"?

I actually know some more things that are good, that the posture still allows for mobility so there are no locking behavior, and that it is stable so you don't accidentally slide (though I don't know if that is a physical thing or more of a muscle memory thing).

Comment: Are you asking specifically about violin, or all instruments - please specify in the tags.

Comment: I changed to the ones I am mostly interested in. (The ones where you use your mouth would need much more complex modeling than I was thinking about)

Comment: This would be a challenging task. You already recognized that good technique is about more than where certain body parts are positioned; you could have your arm in the same place, but with or without tension present. also, good posture is seldom static. It’s not about finding the perfect place and staying there; it’s about freedom to move around it, but coming back to there.

Comment: Finally, whatever gets codified as the recommended posture has a lot to do with tradition, but even more to do with pragmatism. The techniques that evolve to become “correct” are typically the overlap of what is sustainable with what it takes to achieve certain musical goals.

Comment: Perhaps to do this correctly would probably mean identifying styles using data mining on a lot of data, but for a freetime project that is not feasible (mapping pose estimations to an actual human model is probably a master thesis on its own...). But maybe a few metrics can arise so I can throw it on an optimizer and look at one possible solution.